# Using ToArgb() followed by FromArgb() does not result in the original color

Tags: c#, .net, colors, system.drawing.color

This does not work

```
        int blueInt = Color.Blue.ToArgb();
        Color fred = Color.FromArgb(blueInt);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.Blue,fred);
```

Any suggestions?

[Edit]

I'm using NUnit and the output is

failed:

Expected: Color [Blue]

But was:  Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=255]

[Edit]

This works!

```
        int blueInt = Color.Blue.ToArgb();
        Color fred = Color.FromArgb(blueInt);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.Blue.ToArgb(),fred.ToArgb());
```

Comment: using Colour = System.Drawing.Color;

Comment: P.S. the above comment is just humour about colour, not an attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation on `Color.operator ==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.op_equality.aspx):

> This method compares more than the
>   ARGB values of the Color structures.
>   It also does a comparison of some
>   state flags. If you want to compare
>   just the ARGB values of two Color
>   structures, compare them using the
>   ToArgb method.

I'm guessing the state flags are different.

Comment: @lc: The state flags are different because the static Blue property returns a named color, whereas ToArgb does not retain the fact that the color is named, the int only retains the ARGB info.  When converting back to a color, the name is lost, hence the reason why equal does not return true.

Comment: @casperOne: Thanks for the further explanation. I thought it had to do with the name, but to be honest, I wasn't exactly sure. This clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

They won't equal the same, as Color.Blue doesn't equal your colour object, it equals something stored internally, a "new Color(KnownColor.Blue);" to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected this with Assert.AreSame because of the boxing with the value types, but AreEqual should not have this problem.

Could you add which language (I'm assuming C#) your using and which testing framework?

What does `Assert.AreEqual(true, Color.Blue == fred);` result in?

Comment: Yes - it is c#
Using NUnit and the output is:
failed: 
  Expected: Color [Blue]
  But was:  Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=255]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this also works, and I think it's more intuitive

```
    [Test]
    public void ColorTransform()
    {
        var argbInt = Color.LightCyan.ToArgb();
        Color backColor = Color.FromArgb(argbInt);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.LightCyan.A, backColor.A);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.LightCyan.B, backColor.B);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.LightCyan.G, backColor.G);
        Assert.AreEqual(Color.LightCyan.R, backColor.R);
    }
```