# System.Drawing.Color convert FromArgb issue

Tags: c#, .net, colors

I'm saving my color in db in int value.

```
int icolor = System.Drawing.Color.Red.ToArgb();
//result: -65536
```

When convert int to Color than lost property Color.Name. Must return "Red" but property return "ff000000". What I doing wrang?

I need get this one - property Red but not hex value

Comment: There are 4 billion possible colors that can be returned by `FromArgb`. Why should this code path be slowed down by trying to work out whether, from all of the possibilities, you've actually selected one of the named colors, and then returning that one specially? Why do you need it to be `Red`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ToArgb() followed by FromArgb() does not result in the original color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721324/using-toargb-followed-by-fromargb-does-not-result-in-the-original-color)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + "Hex value").Name
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing nothing wrong.

`ff` in hex equals 255 which is the decimal value for the `Red` color, which is being returned by
`System.Drawing.Color.Red.ToArgb();`

If you'd like to get the name of the color, use `System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name`

```
string sRedColorName = System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name;
```

Comment: @user571874 As noted in the answer, you can use `System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name`

Answer (score 2):

> When convert int to Color than lost property Color.Name.

Yes, that's correct. This is how the `Color.Name` property works. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.name.aspx):

> This method returns either the user-defined name of the color, if the color was created from a name, or the name of the known color. For custom colors, the RGB value is returned.

So since you're creating a `Color` object from the integer (RGB) value—not its name—the `Color` structure doesn't recognize it as a named color.

This information is not dynamically determined at runtime by iterating through a map containing all of the known colors and their RGB values, but rather stored in private sentinel fields at the time that the `Color` object is created. You are losing that information in the process of serializing the color information to your database as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up known colors and just colors. When you convert a known color to int, and convert it back to color you lose the name. You have to do this:

```
 int icolor = System.Drawing.Color.Red.ToArgb();

 Color knownColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(icolor).ToKnownColor();
```